# How set release mode in Dart Editor

Tags: dart, dart-editor, dart-pub

With the SDK 1.3, when I use *pub build* in Dart Editor, it generate a lot of files isntead of a one minify file. If I use pub in console with --mode=release, it make only a file.

How I set default mode in Dart Editor?

Answer (score 0):

#### New

DartEditor now has two distinct menu items for debug and release mode.

#### Original

I'm not sure what you are asking for. As far as I know `--mode=release` is default for `pub build`.
I also don't get only one file with `pub build --mode=release`.

You can try to add this to your `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
transformers:
 - $dart2js:
    minify: true
```

Comment: I try, but yet add dart sources.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, executing pub build through Dart editor will run on debug mode. So far, my work around is to run it though command line.

This is an open [issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18242), although there seems to be no plan regarding this yet.